# What is the navigator.platform property for Windows Phones and/or Tablets

Tags: javascript, windows-phone, navigator

I am working on device detection via javascript properties (as opposed to user-agent sniffing) and I don't have access to a Windows Phone, with no luck on the Windows Phone Emulator working properly on a Parallels VM on my Mac...

Could someone please tell me what his Windows Phone or Tablet report while visiting this page: http://www.browserleaks.com/javascript

I am mainly after navigator.platform. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Navigator section I can see (among other things) :

```
User-Agent : Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows Phone OS 7.5; Trident/5.0; IEMobile/9.0; NOKIA; Lumia 710)
Platform : Win32
CPU Class : ARM
```

Comment: For completeness, what does navigator.cpuClass says?

Comment: CPU Class included, it's ARM